# Understanding statements regarding functions & its inverse

Tags: functions

Statement 1:

> If $f :A\mapsto B$ & if $X,Y$ are subsets of $B$, then the inverse image of union of two sets $X$ & $Y$ is the union of inverse images of $X$ & $Y$.

Statement 2:

> Let $f:A\mapsto B$ be a one-to-one correspondence from $A$ to $B$.
>   We define inverse of function , $(f^{-1}): B \mapsto A$ as $f(a)= b$.  This inverse function also has a one-to-one correspondence.

My question is what should i note in these two statements?

Second statement states that the function whose inverse is to be determined should be one-to-one correspondence.

Then what about the inverse in first statement?

Also I have doubt about these notations:

- A)     $(f^{-1})(x)$
- B)     $(f^{-1})(\{x\})$.

Can I say A) is for one one onto function & B) is for any inverse function in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f: X \to Y$ and $B \subset Y$, recall that $f^{-1}(B) = \{x \in X\,:\, f(x) \in B\}$ is the set of all points in $X$ which map to $B$ under $f$.

Statement $1$ says $f^{-1}(A \cup B) = f^{-1}(A) \cup f^{-1}(B)$ for any $A, B \subset Y$. This is true for *any* function.

In this case we are talking about the inverse image of a set; for example if $f$ is not one-to-one, then it may be the case that $f^{-1}(\{y\}) = \{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$, i.e. there are three points $x_1, x_2, x_3$ which are all sent to $y$ by $f$.

In the special case that $f$ is one-to-one, then for each $y \in Y$ there is exactly one $x$ for which $f(x) = y$. In other words, $f^{-1}(\{y\}) = \{x\}$, so in this case $f^{-1}$ is a well-defined *function* with one output for each input.

Note that $f$ does *not* have to be onto for the inverse to be defined. In fact the domain of $f^{-1}$ is $f(X)$, which is in general not equal to $Y$.

Regarding notations, it is true that $f^{-1}(x)$ should be reserved only for defining the inverse function of one-to-one functions. However, you may sometimes see $f^{-1}(x)$, even if $f$ is not one-to-one. In this case it is understood to mean $f^{-1}(\{x\})$.

Answer (score 1):

In statement 1, if the union of A and B is exactly Y, then it would be trivial, else, the result will vary depending on the function f itself. If f is bijective, then the union of A and B need not be exactly Y for the statement 1 to hold.

Comment: I am extremly sorry for the mistake i did. Actually I have edited the question. In statement 1 I means the union of X, Y which are subsets of B.